# Error message 'Class "\Aimeos\MShop\Index\Manager\PgSQL" not available' on aimeos package

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, e-commerce, psql

I am trying install aimeos with postgresql database, and after solved LOTS of problems that occurs when we use other database that isnot mysql, this message is showed on home page

```
Class "\Aimeos\MShop\Index\Manager\PgSQL" not available
```

How to fix this? Whats is missing?

Answer (score 2):

1) after every change !!!!!
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache

2) Edit vendor/aimeos/aimeos-laravel/src/default.php

.....
    'Aimeos' => array(
        'mshop' => array(

```
        'index' => array(

            'manager' => array(

                'attribute' => array(

                    'name' => 'Standard',

                ),

                'catalog' => array(

                    'name' => 'Standard',

                ),

                'price' => array(

                    'name' => 'Standard',

                ),

                'supplier' => array(

                    'name' => 'Standard',

                ),

                'text' => array(

                    'name' => 'PgSQL',

                ),

            ),

        ),

    ),
```

),
3) Edit config/shop.php
    'mshop' => array(

```
    'index' => array(

        'manager' => array(

            'attribute' => array(

                'name' => 'Standard',

            ),

            'catalog' => array(

                'name' => 'Standard',

            ),

            'price' => array(

                'name' => 'Standard',

            ),

            'supplier' => array(

                'name' => 'Standard',

            ),

            'text' => array(

                'name' => 'PgSQL',

            ),

        ),

    ),

),
```

4)  run

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache